# Threejs compass based on camera rotation

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I wanted to make a compass like the one on Facebook:
[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyFAG.png)

The FOV (the slice of pie in the middle of the compass) will rotate based on the FOV of the camera. I have the x, y, and z rotations of the camera, but I was wondering how to translate that into a 2d circle view? Also, the y-rotation of the three.js camera only goes from -PI / 2 to PI / 2

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. What part of the problem don't you know how to do? Show the relevant part of your code.

Answer (score 4):

Solved the same issue using THREE.Spherical()

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
var center = new THREE.Vector3();
var spherical = new THREE.Spherical();
vector.copy( camera.position ).sub( center );
spherical.setFromVector3( vector );
var rot = spherical.theta;
$('#compassSVG > svg')[0].style.transform = 'rotate('+ rot +'rad)';
```

Comment: This is a great answer! and needed in most cases. It may be simplified if using the commonly used orbit controls, where Spherical theta is available via controls.getAzimuthalAngle()

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks!